# Printing .csv files in Python depending on the year?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file.

Each line contains data separated A Comma; each row is ended by
a new line character. So in my file, the first data entry of each line
is a year and the second entry in the line is the title of a film.

For example:

```
1990, Tie Me Up! Tie Me Down!
```

So, it just has a bunch of years, and then movie titles.
My question is, **how do I print the movie title IF it was made before 1990?**
So something like:

```
2015, Spongebob movie
```

wouldn't print.

So far I have:

```
f = open("filmdata.csv","r",encoding="utf-8")
for line in f:
    entries = line.split(",")
    if entries in f < 1990 :
        print(line)
f.close()
```

But nothing is printing out? But it doesn't say error or anything.. I'm trying to keep it in this format.

Comment: since you haven't been a member of S.O. for too long, here it goes: Remember that if any of the answers solved your question, it is a good practice that you mark it as accepted (big checkbox to the left of the answer). It'll give you reputation points, it'll give the person that spent time answering it reputation points and most importantly, it'll help future readers see that the answer was helpful. Please take a look to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 (not only for this post, but for your future questions as well) Cheers **:-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the previous answers will work in your generic case, it is a much better idea to use Python's `csv` module when working with a CSV. It is more extensible, provides handling of more complicated cases (like escaping quotes and data with commas), and is very easy to use.

The following code snippet should work in your case:

```
import csv

with open('filmdata.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', encoding='utf-8')
    for year, movie in data:
        if int(year) < 1990:
            print (year, movie)
```

You can of course modify the `print` to use any format. If you want to separate by commas, this will work:

```
print('{}, {}'.format(year, movie))
```

Comment: @Gabriel Yes--if the CSV file is formatted correctly, e.g. `1950, "Movie, with a comma"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f = open("filmdata.csv","r",encoding="utf-8")
for line in f:
    entries = line.split(",")
    if int(entries[0]) < 1990 :
        print(line)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into using Pandas.  I moc'd up a movie.csv file with 2 colums (year,title).

```
import pandas as pd
movies = pd.read_csv('movie.csv',sep=',',names=["year","title"])
```

Output of movies array:

```
    year    title
0   1990    Movie1
1   1991    Movie2
2   1992    Movie3
3   1993    Movie4
4   1994    Movie5
5   1995    Movie6
6   1996    Movie7
7   1997    Movie8
8   1999    Movie9
9   2000    Movie10
```

Let's say we'd like to see all the movies where the year is over 1994:

```
movies[movies['year']> 1994]

   year    title
5  1995   Movie6
6  1996   Movie7
7  1997   Movie8
8  1999   Movie9
9  2000  Movie10
```